# Cannot open train.txt with white space "My Drive"He

Tags: python, c, google-colaboratory, yolo

I'm trying to custom dataset in yolov3. 
I'm using google colab and google drive to store data and config files.

This is the file content:

```
classes= 1  
train  = /content/gdrive/My 
Drive/mrcnn_fire/yolo_files/yolo_first_example/data/nfpa/train.txt  
valid  = /content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/yolo_files/yolo_first_example/data/nfpa/test.txt  
names = /content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/yolo_files/yolo_first_example/obj.names  
backup = /content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/yolo_files/yolo_first_example/backup/
```

When I run the following command:

```
!./darknet detector train /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/mrcnn_fire/yolo_files/yolo_first_example/obj.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't open file: /content/gdrive/MyDrive/mrcnn_fire/yolo_files/yolo_first_example/data/nfpa/train.txt
```

I think that is related with the white space parsing. 
Hot can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful when configuring the paths in your config files. `obj.data` file needs to have spaces on the path escaped with . Like this: `/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/darknet/train.txt`. But, the paths you have defined in files train.txt and test.txt is not escaped correctly!

link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lTGZsfMaGUpBG4inDIQwIJVW476ibXk_#scrollTo=wkzMqLZV-rF5

Answer (score 0):

Try simplyfy Path by 
`!ln -s "/content/gdrive/My Drive/darknet" /darknet`

and use /darknet instead